# swift Diffable data source error - 'Fatal: supplied item identifiers are not unique. Duplicate identifiers:

Tags: swift, diffabledatasource, uitableviewdiffabledatasource

I think there is a problem with the calendar model or the data I put in the pile, but I can't find it no matter how much I look for it. I'm desperate for help

The contents of the error are as follows

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Fatal: supplied item identifiers are not unique. Duplicate identifiers: {(
        HomeDataSource.Item.calendar
```

```
class HomeDataSource {
    typealias DataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>
    
    private let tableView: UITableView
    private lazy var dataSource = createDataSource()
    private let postType: PostCase
    
    var calendars: [Calendar] = [
        Calendar(date: "haha"),
        Calendar(date: "hhohoho"),
    ]
    
    private var posts: [UserPost]
    
    enum Section: CaseIterable {
        case calendar
        case post
        
        init(rawValue: Int) {
            switch rawValue {
            case 0: self = .calendar
            case 1: self = .post
            default:
                fatalError("not exist section")
            }
        }
    }
    
    enum Item: Hashable {
        case calendar
        case post
    }
    
    init(tableView: UITableView, postType: PostCase) {
        self.tableView = tableView
        self.postType = postType
        self.posts = .init()
    }
    
    func createDataSource() -> UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item> {
        tableView.register(CalendarTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CalendarTableViewCell.identifier)
        tableView.register(UserPostTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: UserPostTableViewCell.identifier)
        tableView.register(EmptyPostTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: EmptyPostTableViewCell.identifier)
        
        
        dataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(tableView: tableView) {
            tableView, indexPath, item in
            switch item {
            case .calendar:
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CalendarTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
                cell.selectionStyle = .none
                return cell
            case .post:
                switch self.postType {
                case .postExist:
                    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: UserPostTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? UserPostTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
                    cell.selectionStyle = .none
                    cell.configure()
                    return cell
                case .friendPostEmpty:
                    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: EmptyPostTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? EmptyPostTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
                    cell.configure(isFriend: true)
                    return cell
                case .ownerPostEmpty:
                    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: EmptyPostTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? EmptyPostTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
                    cell.configure(isFriend: false)
                    return cell
                }
            }
        }
        
        return dataSource
    }

    func updateSnapshot(posts: [UserPost]) {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        
        snapshot.appendSections([.calendar, .post])
        let calendarIds = calendars.map { _ in Item.calendar }
        let postIds = posts.map { _ in Item.post }

        snapshot.appendItems(calendarIds, toSection: .calendar)
        snapshot.appendItems(postIds, toSection: .post)

        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}
```

Calendar model is as follows

```
struct Calendar: Hashable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let date: String
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
      hasher.combine(id)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Calendar, rhs: Calendar) -> Bool {
      lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    init(date: String) {
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

Also, I would like to ask you additionally what should I do if I want to put only one value in the snapshot data?

Comment: Do not name a custom struct `Calendar`. It could interfere with `Foundation.Calendar`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
let calendarIds = calendars.map { _ in Item.calendar }
let postIds = posts.map { _ in Item.post }
```

You just map all the different models into equal Item. Any `Calendar` with unique `id` turns into `Item.calendar` which have no `id`. All of them are equal.

if you still want to us `enum` then I suggest you declare it like that:

```
enum Item {
    case calendar(Calendar)
    case post(UserPost)
}

extension Item: Hashable {
    
    public static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.calendar(let calendar1), .calendar(let calendar2)):
            return calendar1.id == calendar2.id
        case (.post(let post1), .post(let post2)):
            return post1.id == post2.id
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        switch self {
        case .calendar(let calendar):
            hasher.combine("\(calendar.id)_calendar")
        case .post(let post):
            hasher.combine("\(post.id)_post")
        }
    }
    
}
```

This should help you.

Moreover, as `vadian` mentioned, you better not use `Calendar`. Rename it to `UserCalendar` for example.

Comment: You should use entity which you declare as a row for DiffableDataSource. So no, you can’t do that. Please try my code.

Comment: oh, sry. my bad